# how do I add a comment to it like in Instagram and allow other users to comment on the pictures as well

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

Hi when posting a picture in my swift 3 and firebase app how do I add a comment to it like before the picture is actually posted? Like in Instagram and how do I allow other users to comment on the pictures that other people have posted as well? below is every code I have on posting

**Post Cell**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var userImg: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var likesLbl: UILabel!

var post: Post!

var userPostKey: FIRDatabaseReference!

let currentUser = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid")


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func configCell(post: Post, img: UIImage? = nil, userImg: UIImage? = nil) {

    self.post = post

    self.likesLbl.text = "\(post.likes)"

    self.username.text = post.username

    if img != nil {

        self.postImg.image = img

    } else {

        let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: post.postImg)
        ref.data(withMaxSize: 10 * 10000, completion: { (data, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print(error)

            } else {

                if let imgData = data {

                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData){

                        self.postImg.image = img
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    if userImg != nil {

        self.postImg.image = userImg

    } else {

        let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: post.userImg)
        ref.data(withMaxSize: 100000000, completion: { (data, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("couldnt load img")

            } else {

                if let imgData = data {

                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData){

                        self.userImg.image = img
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    _ = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUser!).child("likes").child(post.postKey)
}

@IBAction func liked(_ sender: Any) {

    let likeRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUser!).child("likes").child(post.postKey)

    likeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in

        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {

            self.post.adjustLikes(addlike: true)

            likeRef.setValue(true)

        } else {

            self.post.adjustLikes(addlike: false)

            likeRef.removeValue()
        }
    })
}
}
```

**FeedVC**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import CoreImage

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var postBtn: UIButton!

var posts = [Post]()

var post: Post!

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

var imageSelected = false

var selectedImage: UIImage!

var userImage: String!

var userName: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self

    tableView.dataSource = self

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    imagePicker.delegate = self




    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            self.posts.removeAll()

            for data in snapshot {

                print(data)

                if let postDict = data.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let key = data.key

                    let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)

                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell {

        cell.configCell(post: post)

        return cell

    } else {

        return PostCell()
    }
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        selectedImage = image

        imageSelected = true

    } else {

        print("A valid image wasnt selected")
    }
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    guard imageSelected == true else {

        print("An image must be selected")

        return
    }

    if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.2) {

        let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString

        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()

        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("post-pics").child(imgUid).put(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("image did not save to firebase storage")

            } else {

                print("uploded to firebase storage")

                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                if let url = downloadURL {

                    self.postToFirebase(imgUrl: url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func postToFirebase(imgUrl: String) {

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        let username = data["username"]

        let userImg = data["userImg"]

        let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
            "username": username as AnyObject,
            "userImg": userImg as AnyObject,
            "imageUrl": imgUrl as AnyObject,
            "likes": 0 as AnyObject
        ]

        let firebasePost = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

        firebasePost.setValue(post)

        self.imageSelected = false

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in

        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

@IBAction func postImageTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
{

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
           self.openCamera()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
           self.openGallary()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func openCamera()
    {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func openGallary()
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


@IBAction func SignOutPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

    KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

**Post**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class Post {
private var _username: String!
private var _userImg: String!
private var _postImg: String!
private var _likes: Int!
private var _postKey:  String!
private var _postRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

var username: String {
    return _username
}

var userImg: String {
    return _userImg
}

var postImg: String {
    get {
        return _postImg
    } set {
        _postImg = newValue
    }
}

var likes: Int {
    return _likes
}

var postKey: String {
    return _postKey
}

init(imgUrl: String, likes: Int, username: String, userImg: String) {
    _likes = likes
    _postImg = imgUrl
    _username = username
    _userImg = userImg
}

init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    _postKey = postKey

    if let username = postData["username"] as? String {
        _username = username
    }

    if let userImg = postData["userImg"] as? String {
        _userImg = userImg
    }

    if let postImage = postData["imageUrl"] as? String {
        _postImg = postImage
    }

    if let likes = postData["likes"] as? Int {
        _likes = likes
    }

    _postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(_postKey)

}

func adjustLikes(addlike: Bool) {
    if addlike {
        _likes = likes + 1
    } else {
        _likes = likes - 1
    }
    _postRef.child("likes").setValue(_likes)
}
```

}

Hope this is enough information provided.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please don't just post your full code and ask for full features

Comment: like if i want to add the ability for users when they post a picture to add a comment to the pic how will i do that? Also once a picture is uploaded how can i go about allowing other users to comment on peoples pictures?

Comment: Your question is too broad, bad formatted etc.

Comment: i just want to be able to add a comment to the picture like in Instagram, and add a button to allow user to make comments on pictures but I don't know how to do it or go about asking it properly

Comment: Like i just want to know how to add a description of the picture before posting, and how to allow other user to comment on peoples pictures

Comment: We understand your question. However, you are asking us to implement major features for you. This question will not get answered.

Comment: I just actually need to know where, I need to implement it.

Comment: like where will the code should be under? I don't want anyone to actually implement it just wondering which of the three i should attempt to implement it in?

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for answer? You could probably add some king of view to your post that would hold comments. Instagram only shows a few and then displays the comments in a separate viewController